# Why does a Regular Expression with a star ever end? There will always be empty matches

Tags: regex, algorithm

With a RegEx of "a*" and a search string of "q", why does the RegEx engine not match the empty string an infinite number of times?

Specifically, what mechanism does it use to avoid the repeated match of the same empty string considering that the character index range for the match is start = 0 and end = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of an empty match, it just moves on to the next character - it's just a rule to prevent this infinite loop.

So, essentially: (in pseudo-code)

```
if matchFound
   process match
   if matchLength == 0
      continue from next character
   else
      continue from current character
```

Answer (score 1):

"a*" means "0 or more copies of a"; there is only 1 way to make 0 copies of "a".