# sed - explanation of the strange behavior to replace the repetition of ]\.*

Tags: regex, sed

Please help understand the unexpected sed behaviour below and how to fix.

To replace the repetition of `a` or `b`, I can use `[ab]*`.

```
$ echo "abab" | sed -n 's/[ab]*/X/gp'
X
```

However, `[]\.*]*` does not work as expected to produce `a X b`  as below causing extra substitutions.

```
$ echo "a \.*] b " | sed -n 's/[]\.*]*/X/pg'
XaX X XbX X
```

If replace one by one without repetition expression `*` in regexp pattern, it works.

```
$ echo "a \.*] b " | sed -n 's/[]\.*]/X/pg'
a XXXX b
```

Hence, I suspect repetition expression `*` is causing the issue but not sure what is wrong.

Environment:

```
Mac OS 13.0.1 (22A400)

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.9
```

Comment: `[ab]` means 'a' OR 'b', not 'ab' (try aabb as input) . For ab, try `(ab)`

Comment: What is wrong is that `*` in regex means **0** or more repetitions. Try `\+` for **1** or more.

Comment: `echo "x bb x" | sed -n 's/[ab]*/X/gp'` demonstrates how your first example has exactly the same problem. Output: `XxX X XxX`

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) has a section about the meaning of square brackets, if indeed you are expecting the text between them to match verbatim. Voting to close as typo (though I'm sure there are also duplicates about the meaning of `*` and how it matches no text at all).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801630/what-is-the-difference-between-square-brackets-and-parentheses-in-a-regex and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479566/why-does-a-regular-expression-with-a-star-ever-end-there-will-always-be-empty-m

Answer (score 2):

I find it interesting that the character class tolerates closing-square-bracket in the first position without an escape.   It's nice shorthand that I didn't know about.

```
echo '1[]2[]3[]4' | sed 's/[]]/x/g'
1[x2[x3[x4
```

I thought `]` needed escaping to `\]`, but that first position also seems to make the backslash a literal backslash:

```
echo '1[]2[]3[]4' | sed 's/[\]]*/x/g'
1[]2[]3[]4
```

... this surprisingly replaces nothing because it's looking for literal backslashes to anchor the match.

So it helps to understand what's happening here:

```
$ echo '1[\]2[\]3[\]4' | sed 's/[\]/x/g'
1[x]2[x]3[x]4
$ echo '1[\]2[\]3[\]4' | sed 's/[\]]/x/g'
1[x2[x3[x4
```

... the second is confusing.  Why is there one x?  Oh, because it's matching `\]` as single match.

So, I have to conclude that `]`, closing square bracket has to be escaped everywhere except the first position in a character class.  Somewhat the same for `\` a literal backslash (but that is also tolerated in the last position).  Turns out that's supported by the [IEEE standard here.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) The `]` part.   The meaning of `\` must be discussed elsewhere.

The other thing that's happening is that `*` means "zero or more occurances" so you're also seeing the substitution match all the character boundaries:

```
echo '1[]2[]3[]4' | sed 's/[]]*/x/g'
x1x[x2x[x3x[x4x
```

... to me, that's less surprising.   As the comment said, in BRE, you can use `\+` rather than `*` to mean "one or more."  In ERE, that becomes a simple `+`.

Finally, the "or more" can be confusing:

```
$ echo abab | sed 's/[ab]*/X/g;'
X
$ echo abab | sed 's/[ab]/X/g;'
XXXX
$ echo abcab | sed 's/[ab]/X/g;'
XXcXX
$ echo abcab | sed 's/[ab]*/X/g;'
XcX
```

... aha, yes.   `[ab]*` is going to match uninterrupted strings of a and b as a *single* match.

Comment: technically, I believe `\+` is not valid as "one or more" in BRE (although some versions of sed may allow it). In BRE you should use `\{1,\}` - See [9.3.6(5)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06). Similarly, `?` should be `\{0,1\}`

Answer (score 0):

You started with `echo "abab" | sed -n 's/[ab]*/X/gp'`.
This looks fine because your input only has matching characters. You have the same problem with another input string.

```
echo "string with abab inside" | sed -n 's/[ab]*/X/gp'
XsXtXrXiXnXgX XwXiXtXhX X XiXnXsXiXdXeX
```

This is because `*` also matches a string with 0 length.
You can fix it by replacing `*` with `\+`.

```
echo "string with abab inside" | sed -n 's/[ab]\+/X/gp'
string with X inside

# Or avoid the backslash with the '-r' option
echo "string with abab inside" | sed -rn 's/[ab]+/X/gp'
string with X inside
```

Your case with the other character set works the same way.

```
echo "a \.*] b " | sed -n 's/[]\.*]\+/X/pg'
a X b
```

With BRE, write it like

```
echo "a \.*] b " | sed -rn 's/[]\.*]{1,}/X/pg'
a X b
```